# Entire screen overlay

Tags: android, overlay

just a simple question (hopefully):

Is there any easy way to make a simple translucent screen overlay on android? Just a solid color would work perfectly for starters. I would wager that this wouldnt be started as an activity but run as a service since the overlay should display over everything always until disabled, whether or not the application that hosts this overlay is running/paused/stoped.

It's easy to make an overlay for a specific activity/fragment, but I'd want this overlay to appear over the entire screen regardless of what's on screen (except maybe error dialogs, those seem to take presidence over anything).

Edit: To add more information, apps like "twilight" and "screen filter" seem to be able to do this sort of thing, whereas they are able to display a color at a custom transparency over the entire screen whether or not the app is running.

Comment: Sounds like a custom launcher to me.

Comment: @Tigger , see edited question. It might give a better idea as to what I mean.

Comment: What you need is `WindowManager`. Create a window of type `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and add it to WindowManager, and you have an overlay over everything. PS. A window here is actually just an ordinary View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible to implement entire screen overlay using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission and `WindowManager`, that's how Facebook chat heads works. Basically, you need to add your `View` to `WindowManager` instance, search `WindowManager` for more information.

Comment: Doing some research, this seems to be the general consensus. Could you tell me, what the difference between TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT and SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` is the permission you were looking for. I've updated my answer appropriately.